# I want to replace addEventListener with rxjs observable

Tags: javascript, html, css, rxjs, observable

I am trying to fetch data by XHR by click of button by using rxjs

```
document.getElementById('button')
    .addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log("button clicked");
    });
```

Comment: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/fromEvent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fromEvent(document.getElementById('button'), 'click').pipe(
  switchMap(_ => ajax('yourEndpointUrl'))
).subscribe(
  res => { // do stuff with response },
  err => { // handle error }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose it is a json response

```
fromEvent(document.getElementById('button'), 'click').pipe(
switchMap(e=>from(fetch(...your url)))
switchMap(response=>response.toJson())
).subscribe()
```

Comment: RxJs has the ajax operator. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/ajax.html

Comment: and even better [`fromFetch` operator](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/fetch/fromFetch)